# USB Adapter for Memory Cards

Tags: usb, adapter, memory-card

I am looking for something like a USB adapter for video cards. It is a cable that on one end hooks into a USB port on a computer and on the other accepts any one of a variety of video cards. Essentially it's an "all-in-one" USB adapter for video cards.

I'm told that they are sold all over... does anyone know what it is called or where to find them?

I should clarify, by the way, that by "video card" I mean a memory card for a video camera, and that the goal is to read this video data onto a computer, from a variety of video card types, through a USB port. That way if you go to your friend's house and bring your computer, you can transfer the video data on his video camera to your computer, trusting that the adapter will have a slot for his kind of video card.

Comment: There is **ENORMOUS BIG HUGE** difference between video card and memory card used to store video! DO NOTE IT! I may seem a bit harsh, but it will save you lots and lots of headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A video card is installed inside your computer and you hook your monitor up to it. This is not the device you are asking about.

What you are looking for is called a Card Reader. If you google that you will find tons of stuff. Look for the 6-in-1, 7-in-1, etc multifunction ones. Almost all of them are USB, and they accept lots of cards. They're cheap, too.

Check out Newegg:

http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=69&name=Card-Readers

Apparently this one reads 19 different kinds of cards and it's like $11:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134753

Comment: +1! They are so popular that there are versions which go into computer's front panel or which are integrated into various fan controllers. I even once saw a optical disk drive with integrated memory card reader.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's no such thing.

There are USB video cards, which have VGA or whatever on one side and USB on other side, but there are no USB to PCI-E or USB to AGP adapters. There are USB to PCI adapters, like [this](http://www.arstech.com/item-SSI2-PCI-card-ssi2_pci.html) one, but I don't see any reason why to use USB to PCI adapter and a PCI video card, if you can get a USB video card which will have more or less same performance as PCI video card.

There were some ExpressCard video cards, but they were pretty rare and I don't think anyone makes them any more.

**EDIT** This answer was to original question.

Comment: Check out his second paragraph. He doesn't mean video card. He just wants a card reader.

Comment: @Chris When I started writing this answer, he didn't mention memory cards at all.

Comment: Ah - I didn't know he edited it.